# Connect to AS/400 thru TN5250

Tags: ip

pls help me how will i get ip address for TN5250? i have installed TN5250 evaluation free copy for 30 days to my laptop, os is windows vista home pack.trying to connect the session with my laptop ip address but giving error.pls help me, emailed to mocha soft but didnt get reply. they advised me to contact local as/400 administrator...how will i contact that. i like to use at my home and not being able to connect.........